# Could no resolve org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo class?

Tags: java, apache-poi, maven-3, openxml

I'm trying to sign a Doc with POI OOXML in a maven project as mentioned here https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/dsig/SignatureInfo.html

```
public boolean verify(InputStream inputStream) {

    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(inputStream);
     SignatureConfig sic = new SignatureConfig();
     sic.setOpcPackage(pkg);
     SignatureInfo si = new SignatureInfo();
     si.setSignatureConfig(sic);
     boolean isValid = si.validate();
    return isValid; 
}
```

my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.me</groupId>
<artifactId>docx-signer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>docx-signer</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.51</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.51</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I could not resolve this class `org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo`
While it's being in the documentation !!

Any advice ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this bit here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Support for OOXML signatures was only added in Apache POI 3.11 beta 3. 3.10.1 is too old, and doesn't contain the support

Your pom dependency therefore needs to instead be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.11-beta3</version>
</dependency>
```

(Or a newer one when new versions are released)